# How to exchange JMSSampler to my own sampler in test plan?

Tags: jmeter, jmx

I created my own sampler extending JMSSampler. I attached new jar file with this new class to lib/ext directory in jmeter.
I had prepared a test plan before which used JMSSampler. I wanted it to use my new sampler called PointToPointSampler and I was thinking that it would be a small change in jmx file. 
A section in jmx file starts like this:
<JMSSampler guiclass="JMSSamplerGui" testclass="JMSSampler" testname="Add rule" enabled="true">
When I changed testclass "JMSSampler" to "PointToPointSampler" nothing happens.
I also tried adding:
<stringProp name="classname">PointToPointSampler</stringProp> 
but it didn't work.

Any ideas what should I change?

Comment: I doubt this will work in way you are trying to achieve it. I think you have to create GUI class for your sampler class which you can use in testplan.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I created a new GUI class and now it works! Thank you.

Comment: welcome :). JMeter is designed in that way only.